# The bases of 2 orthogonal subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Why if 2 subspaces are orthogonal, then their bases must be orthogonal, too?

My subspaces are $U$ and $V$ (pretty generic). Then let $u$ and $v$ be elements of these, i.e. $u \in U$ and $v \in V$. So there exist  $\alpha_i$, $i \in \{1,\ldots , n\}$ so that $u =  \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \cdot u_i$.
Similarly, $v =  \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j \cdot v_j$.
(Here $\dim(U) = n$ and $\dim(V) = m$).

Then, by definition, since $U \perp V, \langle u, v\rangle = 0$, i.e. $$\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \cdot u_i, \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j \cdot v_j\right\rangle,$$ which I have rewritten as $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j \cdot \langle u_i,v_j\rangle = 0$.

Now what?

Comment: Think carefully about the definitions---what does it *mean* for two subspaces to be orthogonal?

Comment: Are the bases contained in their respective subspaces?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. You can at least try some small examples to try to guess the answer to your question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did and i arrived at something which doesn't look very promising. Care to take a look, please?

Comment: @EscuEsculescu So, two subspaces $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal if their elements are mutually orthogonal.  What does it mean for two bases to be orthogonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $U \perp V$, we are given that $u \perp v$ for any $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.  Now, suppose that
$$ \mathcal{U} = \{u_1, u_2, \dotsc, u_m\}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\mathcal{V} = \{v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_n\} $$
are bases for $U$ and $V$, respectively.  We want to show that for each $u_i\in\mathcal{U}$ and $v_j \in \mathcal{V}$, we have $u_i \perp v_j$; so let $u_i$ and $v_j$ be two such elements.  But $\mathcal{U} \subseteq U$, which implies that $u_i\in U$.  Similarly, $v_j \in V$.  By the hypothesis that $U \perp V$, we have $u_i \perp v_j$, which is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

This is true by definition. Two subspaces $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal if and only if for every $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ we have $u$ orthogonal to $v$. Since basis vectors are just particular choices of $u$ and $v$ they must be orthogonal.